# Find the second largest sum of consecutive integers in array

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone please provide and explain a solution to this problem

I have an array of integers

```
int[] arr = {1,6,2,3,8};
```

I want to find to second largest sum of consecutive integers in the array and also display the element pair who's sum produces the second largest number

For example from the above array, the sum of consecutive integers is

- 1+6 = 7
- 6+2 = 8
- 2+3 = 5
- 3+8 = 11

The output of the program is

```
8 by elements 6,2
```

Conditions for this problem are

1. Must be done in a single loop
2. Must not use new array
3. Must not sort the given array
4. Must not use Collection Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long max = Long.MIN_VALUE + 1, secondMax = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        int positionMax = -1, positionSecondMax = -1;
        int[] arr = {1,6,2,3,8};

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
            if(arr[i] + arr[i + 1] > max){
                secondMax = max;
                positionSecondMax = positionMax;
                max = (long)arr[i] + (long)arr[i + 1];
                positionMax = i;
            }
            else if(arr[i] + arr[i + 1] < max && arr[i] + arr[i + 1] > secondMax){
                secondMax = (long)arr[i] + (long)arr[i + 1];
                positionSecondMax = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(secondMax + " by elements " + arr[positionSecondMax] + ", " + arr[positionSecondMax + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you must store at each stage the positions of the max and secondmax in variables to be able to display the elements at the end.

Comment: Why did you use a counter variable?

Comment: Will not work for `int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 2 }`

Comment: @MT0 you can't make that argument as the number constraints are not given. We will set the max value to be 1 less than minimum value possible in the constraints given.

Comment: The number constraints are given - it is an `int` array so it is between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the consecutive sum can be between `2*Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `2*Integer.MAX_VALUE` (which will overflow an `int`).

Comment: Yes you are right, i should consider those constraints if explicit constraints are not given. See the updated answer with long.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Addition{
  public int leftOperand, rightOperand;
  public int sum;
  public Addition(int left, int right){
    sum = (this.leftOperand = left) + (this.rightOperand = right);
  }



  public static Addition get(int[] array){
    // initialize top two memory
    Addition max = null, secMax = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; $i++){
      Addition add = new Addition(array[i], array[i + 1]);
      if(max == null){
        max = secMax = add; // initialize them for the first time
        continue;
      }
      if(secMax.sum < add.sum){
        secMax = add; // displaces second max
        if(max.sum < add.sum){ // add is already second max. This doesn't need to be outside the former if block.
          secMax = max;
          max = add;
        }
      }
    }
    return secMax;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt.One loop, store sum operands and sum for both the highest and second highest sum.

```
    int[] arr = {1,6,2,3,8};

    int highestFirstOperand = -1;
    int highestSecondOperand = -1;
    int secondHighestFirstOperand = -1;
    int secondHighestSecondOperand = -1;
    int highestSum = -1;
    int secondHighestSum = -1;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (i<arr.length-1) {
            int thisSum = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
            if (thisSum > highestSum) {
                secondHighestSum = highestSum;
                secondHighestFirstOperand = highestFirstOperand;
                secondHighestSecondOperand = highestSecondOperand;
                highestSum = thisSum;
                highestFirstOperand = arr[i];
                highestSecondOperand = arr[i+1];
            } else if (thisSum > secondHighestSum) {
                secondHighestSum = thisSum;
                secondHighestFirstOperand = arr[i];
                secondHighestSecondOperand = arr[i + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(secondHighestSum + " by elements " + secondHighestFirstOperand + "," + secondHighestSecondOperand);
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through each consecutive pair of the array and keep track of where and what the highest consecutive sum is and where and what the second highest consecutive sum is and updates them as it gets higher values.

You need to use `long` to store the consecutive sums as adding two `int`s may overflow the value if an `int` is used to store the sum.

```
public class SecondLargest {
    public static int findSecondLargestConsecutiveSum( final int[] array ){
        if ( array == null )
          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot find consecutive sum in a null array" );
        if ( array.length < 3 )
          return -1;

        long largest         = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long secondLargest   = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        int largestPos       = -1;
        int secondLargestPos = -1;
        long sum;
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; ++i )
        {
            sum = array[i] + array[i+1];
            if ( sum > largest ) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                secondLargestPos = largestPos; 
                largest = sum;
                largestPos = i;
            }
            else if ( sum < largest && sum > secondLargest ){
                secondLargest = sum;
                secondLargestPos = i;
            }
        }
        return secondLargestPos;
    }

    public static String formatSecondLargest( final int[] array ){
        final int pos = findSecondLargestConsecutiveSum( array );
        if ( pos == -1 )
            return "Array does not have a second largest consecutive sum.";

        return String.format( "%d by elements %d,%d at position %d", (long) array[pos] + (long) array[pos+1], array[pos], array[pos+1], pos );
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        System.out.println(formatSecondLargest( new int[]{ 1,6,2,3,8 } ) );
        System.out.println(formatSecondLargest( new int[]{ 1,6,2,3,8,3 } ) );
        System.out.println(formatSecondLargest( new int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE } ) );
        System.out.println(formatSecondLargest( new int[]{ Integer.MIN_VALUE+1, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE+2 } ) );
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
8 by elements 6,2 at position 1
8 by elements 6,2 at position 1
Array does not have a second largest consecutive sum.
-4294967295 by elements -2147483647,-2147483648 at position 0
```

Comment: *Can anyone please provide and explain a solution to this problem*, can't really say you covered the explain part.

Comment: Explanation added - the algorithm is simple as it just iterates over the list tracking where the maximum and second maximum sums are and what their values are, updating them as it finds higher values.